# Conditional update strings in collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to update all strings in a List, that do not start with "http://" to start with "http://"

In a foreach I would do something like this:

`url = url.StartsWith("http://") ? url : url.Insert(0, "http://");`

Comment: Linq is not meant for mutating a collection.  You could use it to create a new collection but you might as well just use a `foreach` loop for this.

Comment: Linq is for _querying_, not _updating.  There's nothing wrong with using `foreach` for actions with side-effects.

Comment: @DStanley: `foreach` wouldn't be terribly useful here, whereas a straight `for` loop would.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: I suggest you try it :) (Hint: the iteration variable in a `foreach` variable is read-only...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, did not understand we were looping over a List<string> and not an object with a string property :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a regular `for` loop - that's the simplest way of *modifying* the collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    string url = list[i];
    if (!url.StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        list[i] = "http://" + url;
    }
}
```

If you're happy to create a *new* collection, it's simple:

```
var modifiedList = list.Select(url => url.StartsWith("http://") ? url : "http://" + url)
                       .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
yourlist.Where(_ => !_.StartsWith("http://")).ToList().ForEach(_ => _.Insert(0, "http://"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this by using `Union` is:

```
var result =
    list.Where(url => url.StartsWith("http://"))
        .Union(list.Where(url => !url.StartsWith("http://")).Select(url => $"http://{url}"))
        .ToList();
```